# How to create a heart shape using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I've found the following CSS in one of the answers here on SO and I was wondering why does it create the desired heart shape:

```css
#heart { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 90px; 
} 

#heart:before, #heart:after { 
    position: absolute; 
    content: ""; 
    left: 50px; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 80px; 
    background: red; 
    border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0; 
    transform: rotate(-45deg); 
    transform-origin: 0 100%; 
} 

#heart:after { 
    left: 0; 
    transform: rotate(45deg); 
    transform-origin :100% 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div id="heart"></div>
```

Please can someone explain?

Comment: Heart with Pulse Animation : https://youtu.be/Jq4diUd10Zs

Answer (score 55, accepted):

### CSS3 Mon Amour - A 4 Step Love Afair

There are a few steps for creating heart shape using CSS3:

1. Create a block-level element such as a `<div>` in your DOM and assign it with `id="heart"` and apply CSS:

   ```
   #heart {
        position:relative; 
        width:100px; 
        height:90px;
        margin-top:10px; /* leave some space above */
   }
   ```
2. Now using pseudo-element `#heart:before` we create a red box with one rounded edge like this:

   ```
   #heart:before {
       position: absolute; 
       content: ""; 
       left: 50px; 
       top: 0; 
       width: 52px; 
       height: 80px; 
       background: red; /* assign a nice red color */
       border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0; /* make the top edge round */ 
   }
   ```

   Your heart should now look like this:

   [image]
3. Let us assign a little rotation to that by adding:

   ```
   #heart:before {
       -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* 45 degrees rotation counter clockwise */
          -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
           -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
            -o-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
               transform: rotate(-45deg); 
       -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%; /* Rotate it around the bottom-left corner */
          -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%; 
           -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%; 
            -o-transform-origin: 0 100%; 
               transform-origin: 0 100%;
   }
   ```

   And we now get:

   [image]

   Already starting to come together :).
4. Now for the right part we basically need the same shape only rotated
   45 degrees clockwise instead of counter clockwise. **To avoid code duplication we attach the css
   of `#heart:before` also to `#heart:after`, and then apply the change
   in position and in angle:**

   ```
   #heart:after { 
       left: 0; /* placing the right part properly */
       -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* rotating 45 degrees clockwise */
          -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); 
           -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
            -o-transform: rotate(45deg); 
               transform: rotate(45deg); 
       -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%; /* rotation is around bottom-right corner this time */
          -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%; 
           -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%; 
            -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%; 
               transform-origin :100% 100%; 
   }
   ```

   And voilà! a complete heart shaped `<div>`:

   [image]

**Snippet without any prefix:**

```css
#heart {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#heart::before, #heart::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 52px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  background: red;
}

#heart::before {
  left: 50px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

#heart::after {
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="heart"></div>
```

Comment: Fascinating, really great work! For others, do not forget to change the first `#heart:before {` to `#heart:before, #heart:after {`. Yotam said this though, but I was too fast and did not see this information while trying the code.

Comment: Maybe add another image after step 4 where the 2nd half is another color to better show the layers? To better show the 'trick' being applied :)

Comment: Also, the vendor prefixes are not needed for those properties :) I've also removed them from the question to simplify

Answer (score 21):

A new idea with less of code (https://css-tip.com/image-heart-shape/)

```css
.heart {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-image: radial-gradient(red 69%, #0000 70%) 84.5%/50%;
  clip-path: polygon(-41% 0, 50% 91%, 141% 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
<div class="heart" style="width:100px"></div>
<div class="heart" style="width:50px"></div>
```

Using mask, we can apply it to an image:

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
  --_m: radial-gradient(#000 69%,#0000 70%) 84.5%/50%;
  -webkit-mask-box-image: var(--_m);
             mask-border: var(--_m);
  clip-path: polygon(-41% 0,50% 91%, 141% 0);
}

/* fallback until better support for mask-border */
@supports not (-webkit-mask-box-image: var(--_m)) { 
  img {
   --_m:
     radial-gradient(at 70% 31%,var(--c) 29%,#0000 30%),
     radial-gradient(at 30% 31%,var(--c) 29%,#0000 30%),
     linear-gradient(#000 0 0) bottom/100% 50% no-repeat;
   -webkit-mask: var(--_m);
           mask: var(--_m);
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  place-content: center;
  gap: 30px;
  background: pink;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px #ff3e60)
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1027/300/300"  alt="the face of a beautiful girl">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/64/300/300"  alt="another beautiful girl">
```

---

**Old answer**

Here is another idea using **one** element and relying on **multiple backgrounds** to achieve the heart shape. You can also easily adjust the size by only changing the width:

```css
.heart {
  width:200px;
  background:
   radial-gradient(circle at 60% 65%, red 64%, transparent 65%) top left,
   radial-gradient(circle at 40% 65%, red 64%, transparent 65%) top right,
   linear-gradient(to bottom left, red 43%,transparent 43%) bottom left ,
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,red 43%,transparent 43%) bottom right;
  background-size:50% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;
}
.heart::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart">
</div>
<div class="heart" style="width:100px">
</div>
<div class="heart" style="width:60px">
</div>
<div class="heart" style="width:30px">
</div>
```

[image: CSS heart shape]

You can also use `mask` and you can have any kind of coloration:

```css
.heart {
  width:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-mask:
     radial-gradient(circle at 60% 65%, red 64%, transparent 65%) top left,
     radial-gradient(circle at 40% 65%, red 64%, transparent 65%) top right,
     linear-gradient(to bottom left, red 43%,transparent 43%) bottom left ,
     linear-gradient(to bottom right,red 43%,transparent 43%) bottom right;
  -webkit-mask-size:50% 50%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  mask:
     radial-gradient(circle at 60% 65%, red 64%, transparent 65%) top left,
     radial-gradient(circle at 40% 65%, red 64%, transparent 65%) top right,
     linear-gradient(to bottom left, red 43%,transparent 43%) bottom left ,
     linear-gradient(to bottom right,red 43%,transparent 43%) bottom right;
  mask-size:50% 50%;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  background:linear-gradient(red,blue);
}
.heart::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart">
</div>
<div class="heart" style="width:100px;background:linear-gradient(45deg,grey 50%,purple 0)">
</div>
<div class="heart" style="width:60px;background:radial-gradient(red,yellow,red)">
</div>
<div class="heart" style="width:30px;background:blue">
</div>
```

[image: CSS heart shape with gradient coloration]

### **How does it works?**

The whole shape is combined using 4 gradients: 2 gradients to create the top part and 2 for the bottom parts. each gradient is taking 1/4 of size and placed at a corner.

Use a different color for each gradient to clearly identify the puzzle

```css
.heart {
  width:200px;
  background:
   radial-gradient(circle at 60% 65%, red  64%, grey 65%) top left,
   radial-gradient(circle at 40% 65%, blue 64%, black 65%) top right,
   linear-gradient(to bottom left, green 43%,black 43%) bottom left ,
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,purple 43%,grey 43%) bottom right;
  background-size:50% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;
  border:5px solid yellow;
}
.heart::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart">
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing answer, do you mind kindly explain a little bit to how you achieve the effect in the first snnipet?

Comment: @James here is an illustration to understand what the clip-path is doing: https://jsfiddle.net/7xb50yrm/ .. for the border part I invite you to read this answer to understand how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56915094/8620333