# How to write on the heart?

Tags: html, css, geometry, css-shapes

Following this: [Did CSS break my heart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189966/did-css-break-my-heart), I now have this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arfc63Le/2/), which has this HTML:

```
<div id="heart"><span>M + G</span></div>
```

and this (new) CSS:

```
span {
  z-index: 4;
}
```

However, the letters are still *behind* the heart, while my goal is to place them in the centre of it and for a start I thought I had to get them in front of the heart, but this fails, any idea *please*?

Comment: Please don't use "funny titles". This way it will be more likely that people searching for the same solution will find your questions. And SO will suggest appropriate duplicates.

Comment: That was not funny IMHO @Oriol, but if you have any suggestion, please let me know or feel free to edit the question!

Comment: Maybe "funny" isn't the right word, but "Did CSS break my heart" seems to mean CSS caused emotional pain to you.

Comment: Oh you were talking about my old question @Oriol, sorry didn't get that! I see what you mean and I will be more careful in the future. I did, a bit. ;p

Comment: A working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tzi/r9yb0zh0/

Comment: @tzi, can you please post that as an answer? :)

Comment: @gsamaras Sadly not, because this question is marked as duplicate. Be cautious with titles next time ;)

Comment: @tzi your solution is a beauty! Yes sir!

Comment: @gsamaras Is it just me that actually likes the title?

Comment: @choz thank you, I felt that this was the appropriate title for the question, thus you are not alone! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative,...... ) and your `span` elemet dosnt have `position` property.

```
#heart:before, #heart:after {
    z-index: -1; // because the text will be placed behind heart.
}
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/arfc63Le/3/)

or you just add `position: relative` to your span.

Comment: Any idea on how to move the text of the heart with this solution?

Comment: move it where ? centered ?

Comment: Yes, you know in the center of the heart.

Comment: yes just add `text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;` to `#heart` see [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/arfc63Le/5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

Update to center text:

```
span {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 60px;
  z-index: 4;
}

#heart {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  /* leave some space above */
}
```

Comment: I saw John's solution first, so I may accept that, but I will upvote something else you have posted in SO, as a sign of my thanks to you.

Comment: Please don't, keep SO clean :) Kudos to John, and happy you've found what you were looking for, though :)

Comment: I upvoted something I read and thought it deserved the upvote!! I agree with you, if it was that you didn't have something I could admire, then I wouldn't upvote. ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index), `z-index` can only be applied to a positioned element.

Simply set the `span` to `position:relative;`:

```
span {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tva738wq/)