# HTML input border-image with svg not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add image border to input field using image-border options but it's doesn't show me the SVG image as a border.

Any ideas why?

```css
#inputCode{
   position: absolute;
   top: 35%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 745px;
   border-image: url(../images/white_rubrick.svg);
   font-size: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: transparent;
   color: white;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<input 
      type="text" 
      name="inputCode" 
      id="inputCode" 
      size="8"
      maxlength="8" 
      autofocus 
      placeholder="PUT YOUR CODE HERE" 
      style="text-transform:uppercase"/>
```

Expected:
[image: expected]

The problem:
[image: the probelm]

Comment: You don't have enough parameters in your border image statetement - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Comment: you need to also define a border-style (related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56915094/8620333)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want it to be an image? Isn't it better to generate the expected with code only? I mean using `-webkit-appearance: none;`

```css
.code-input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input class="code-input" value="Put your code here" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the CSS to this:

```css
#inputCode{
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 745px;
    border-image: url(./border.svg) 25% repeat;
    border-width:25px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
```

```html
<input 
    type="text" 
    name="inputCode" 
    id="inputCode" 
    size="8"
    maxlength="8" 
    autofocus 
    placeholder="PUT YOUR CODE HERE" 
    style="text-transform:uppercase"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, your input is appreciated! Please edit your answer so that it (a) put the answer into context, (b) explains what (changes) you did.

Answer (score 0):

Add `border-radius` to the desired px -

```css
#inputCode {
   position: absolute;
   top: 35%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 500px;
   border-image: url(../images/white_rubrick.svg);
   border-radius: 30px;
   font-size: 20px;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: transparent;
   color: white;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<input 
      type="text" 
      name="inputCode" 
      id="inputCode" 
      size="8"
      maxlength="8" 
      autofocus 
      placeholder="PUT YOUR CODE HERE" 
      style="text-transform:uppercase"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `border-image: url(../images/white_rubrick.svg);` to `border-image: url(../images/white_rubrick.svg) 20% round;`. If this does not work, try changing 20% round to 30% or 50% round.