# How to make image repeat itself instead of stretching?

Tags: html, css

I have background image which is needed to be repeated to it's content like that:
[image: like that]

But using this code:

```css
.imgbord {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/LGlfFuU.png');
  background-repeat: round;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: 42px auto; width: 75%;">
  <div class="imgbord">some random content out here</div>
</div>
```

I get this:

[image: i get this]

Comment: are you sure you want to repeat? it seems you want 100% in background-size

Comment: I want to repeat the part of it, so it's looks like I shown. @TemaniAfif

Comment: I need to repeat it both in Y and X. So I don't really know how to make it. @Pete

Comment: share the background you are using so we can understand what you have

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/wdmJxi7 @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `border-image`

```css
.imgbord {
  border:4px solid transparent;
  border-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/LGlfFuU.png') 4 fill round;
  color: white;
  padding:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
}

body {
  background:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgbord">some random content out here</div>


<div class="imgbord">some content</div>
```

Related to understand how it works and how to adjust the values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56915094/8620333

Comment: Everything is ok, but I need to remove this smoothing somehow on the borders.

Comment: @JackGlow you need to play with the values. It's a bit tricky but I linked another answer that details how it works so you know how to do

Comment: @JackGlow I made an update, a slice of 4 is better and you can use round for the repeat