# Is it possible to set border-image and background both with repeating-linear-gradient property?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients, repeating-linear-gradient

I'm trying to set `border-image` and `background` properties both with the `repeating-linear-gradient` option, but with different values for the same `<div>` element. I don't know how to do it, because with my attempt it seems the gradients parameters are overlapped and it also seems the page takes the last values setted.

Here's the code and the output I got:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background:
    linear-gradient(217deg, rgba(255,0,0, .8), rgba(255,0,0,0) 70.71%),
    linear-gradient(127deg, rgba(0,255,0, .8), rgba(0,255,0,0) 70.71%),
    linear-gradient(336deg, rgba(0,0,255, .8), rgba(0,0,255,0) 70.71%);
}

.under_banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    top: 80%;
    border-width: 10px 0 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: repeating-linear-gradient(145deg, #ff0000, #ff9020 50%);
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(130deg, #f6d808, #ffc107 10%);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="under_banner">
    <p>Hello StackOverflow Community!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: Output]

As you can see, `.under_banner` has `top-border` property, in fact the `repeating-linear-gradient` is not symmetric with the `background` one. I'd like to get different gradients for each property just with one div, if possible.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple background:

```css
body {
    background:
    linear-gradient(217deg, rgba(255,0,0, .8), rgba(255,0,0,0) 70.71%),
    linear-gradient(127deg, rgba(0,255,0, .8), rgba(0,255,0,0) 70.71%),
    linear-gradient(336deg, rgba(0,0,255, .8), rgba(0,0,255,0) 70.71%);
}

.under_banner {
    width: 100%;
    left:0;
    height: 20%;
    bottom:0;
    background: 
      repeating-linear-gradient(130deg, #f6d808, #ffc107 10%) bottom/100% calc(100% - 10px),
      repeating-linear-gradient(145deg, #ff0000, #ff9020 50%);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="under_banner">
    <p>Hello StackOverflow Community!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Or adjust your code like below, you are simply missing the slice property:

```css
body {
    background:
    linear-gradient(217deg, rgba(255,0,0, .8), rgba(255,0,0,0) 70.71%),
    linear-gradient(127deg, rgba(0,255,0, .8), rgba(0,255,0,0) 70.71%),
    linear-gradient(336deg, rgba(0,0,255, .8), rgba(0,0,255,0) 70.71%);
}

.under_banner {
    width: 100%;
    left:0;
    height: 20%;
    bottom:0;
    border-width: 10px 0 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: repeating-linear-gradient(145deg, #ff0000, #ff9020 50%) 10; /* added the slice here */
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(130deg, #f6d808, #ffc107 10%);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="under_banner">
    <p>Hello StackOverflow Community!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Related for more details: [border-image-slice for gradient border image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56914337/8620333)