# CSS border-top gradient from top to bottom

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make border-top css rule for element with gradient from top to bottom. I'm using this code:

`border-top: 15px solid transparent; border-image: linear-gradient(to top, #0a2028, #104359) 1;`

or this:

```
border-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #0a2028, #104359) 1;
```

but this wont work.

I want to achieve something like using by this one:

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #225763, #062532);
```

Comment: Here is example: https://jsfiddle.net/T02my/m9gf0bwx/5/

Comment: make the slice equal to border-width (change the `1` to `15`): related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56915094/8620333

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

And the css:

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
}
```

[Here is the example you can try](https://codepen.io/Shuree/pen/mdRMJNE)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I understand that it makes gradient related to ALL border. But how to apply this only to border-top?

Comment: change `border` to `border-top`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            button {
                background: none;
                text-decoration: inherit;
                font-family: system-ui;
                font-size: 1rem;
                padding: 1rem 2rem;
            }

            .border-gradient {
                border: 10px solid;
                border-image-slice: 1;
                border-width: 5px;
            }

            .border-gradient-purple {
                border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
            }

            .border-gradient-green {
                border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #00C853, #B2FF59);
            }

            body {
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }
            body > div {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
            }
            body > div > div {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 1rem;
            }

            .on-dark {
                background: #222;
            }
            .on-dark button {
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="on-light">
                <button class="border-gradient border-gradient-purple">
                    I have a gradient
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="on-dark">
                <button class="border-gradient border-gradient-purple">
                    I have a gradient
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="on-light">
                <button class="border-gradient border-gradient-green">
                    I have a gradient
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="on-dark">
                <button class="border-gradient border-gradient-green">
                    I have a gradient
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, but how to apply this only to border-top?