# background-image-source not working with linear-gradient as per Figma

Tags: css, linear-gradients, border-image

I'm trying to implement a nice linear-gradient border on a container. However, it's not playing ball and the border is just appearing in the bottom left, top left, top right, bottom right in a little square. Not actually appearing around the entire border.

Below is the css code:

```
.blur > .elementor-column-wrap {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border: 1px solid;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(
        310.55deg, 
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 29.24%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 97.14%
    );
}

@supports ( backdrop-filter: blur(5px) ) or ( -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px) )  {
    .blur > .elementor-column-wrap {
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
        backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    }
}

@supports not ( backdrop-filter: blur(5px) ) and ( -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px) ) {
    .blur > .elementor-column-wrap {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.82);
    }
}
```

Any idea why this isn't working please let us know, the border code was also taken straight from Figma as the 'recommended' code to use but evidently it's got some issues with use case.

Image below of the displayed border currently:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `border-image-slice`

```css
.box {
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
   box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
   border: 10px solid;
   border-image-source: linear-gradient(
        310.55deg, 
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 29.24%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 97.14%
    );
   border-image-slice: 10;
}


body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56915094/8620333

Comment: That works a treat, only think is border-radius isn't working with the border. Is that simply because it doesn't work when combined or?

Comment: @DanielVickers if you want radius check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51496204/8620333