# How can I change color of the heart-button after click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

You can see in my code below I used pseudo-elements and actually that's why I got confused. Any idea how can I change color after click on button?

```css
.heart {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute; 
  left: 45%; top: 45%;
  width: 50px;
}

.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
}

.heart:before {
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
}

.heart:after {
  left: 25px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="heart" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: another idea to build a heart: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51216413/8620333 maybe easier to change color using CSS variable

Comment: Or just, you know, use a heart character: ❤ or emoji : ❤️ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `currentColor` as the `background-color` for all elements. Set the `color` of `.heart` to red, and set it to black when it's focused or active:

```css
.heart {
  color: red;
  background-color: currentColor;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute; 
  left: 45%; top: 45%;
  width: 50px;
}

.heart::before,
.heart::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: currentColor;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
}

.heart:before {
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
}

.heart:after {
  left: 25px;
  top: 0;
}

.heart:focus {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="heart" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

If you want the color change to remain even after you click somewhere else, and you would like to toggle the color on click, you might want to use a checkbox with label instead:

```css
.heart {
  color: red;
  background-color: currentColor;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  top: 45%;
  width: 50px;
}

.heart-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.heart::before,
.heart::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: currentColor;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
}

.heart:before {
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
}

.heart:after {
  left: 25px;
  top: 0;
}

.heart-checkbox:checked + .heart {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="heart-checkbox" id="heart-checkbox">
  <label class="heart" for="heart-checkbox"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's only *when* you click on it, you can use the *active* state (see example code below):

```css
    .heart:active, .heart:active:before, .heart:active:after {
        background-color: black;
    }
```

If you want to change color while the element is in focus, *focus* state:

```css
    .heart:focus, .heart:focus:before, .heart:focus:after {
        background-color: black;
    }
```

If you want to change it "permenantly", you can use JavaScript to add a class to the element (with the desired colors declared in CSS).

```css
.heart {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute; 
  left: 45%; top: 45%;
  width: 50px;
}

.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
}

.heart:before {
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
}

.heart:after {
  left: 25px;
  top: 0;
}

.heart:active, .heart:active:before, .heart:active:after {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="heart" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two images red and white for example. and you can also use javascript.

## html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="a-heart" href="#"><img src="redHeart.png" id="heart" class="red"></a>
</div>
```

## javascript

```
let heart = document.getElementById('heart');
heart.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if(heart.classList.contains('red')){
        heart.classList.remove('red');
        heart.classList.add('white');
        heart.src = 'whiteHeart.png';
    }else{
        heart.classList.remove('white');
        heart.classList.add('red');
        heart.src = 'redHeart.png';
    }
});
```