# Make svg element adapt to container dimensions

Tags: css, svg

I've the following SVG path that is intended to be used as a border of any possible width and height. But currently, I am struggling with the following 2 points and appreciate a lot if some can share some ideas :-)

1. Is it possible to detach SVG from the viewBox and adapt to parent dimension?

2. Is it possible to detach SVG stroke width and always be as defined? (4px)

```css
.c500x200 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.c200x600 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

svg path {
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke: #d22f2c;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='c500x200'>
  <svg data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 357.5 248" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
  </defs>
  <path transform="translate(-289 -320)" d="M623,565.5H291.5v-243h341v231s-1,12,14,12"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class='c200x600'>
  <svg data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 357.5 248" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
  </defs>
  <path transform="translate(-289 -320)" d="M623,565.5H291.5v-243h341v231s-1,12,14,12"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Just because you can't/don't want to answer doesn't mean you should vote if for close

Comment: 1. No 2. No. See https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66037352/how-to-make-a-resizable-heart-in-css-with-a-border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to detach SVG from the viewBox and adapt to parent dimension?

The `viewBox` is the way you get an SVG to adapt to a parent's dimensions.  What I think you are asking is whether it is possible to get a viewBox to stretch to fill a parent container.

The answer is yes.  You can do that using `preserveAspectRatio="none"`.  But note that this stretches the scale of the shape. So curves in the shape will be distorted.  See below.

> Is it possible to detach SVG stroke width and always be as defined? (4px)

Yes.  You can set `vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke` on the path elements.  See below.

```css
.c500x200 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: linen;
}

.c200x600 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: linen;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

svg path {
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke: #d22f2c;
  fill: none;
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}
```

```html
<div class='c500x200'>
  <svg data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 357.5 248" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
  </defs>
  <path transform="translate(-289 -320)" d="M623,565.5H291.5v-243h341v231s-1,12,14,12"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class='c200x600'>
  <svg data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 357.5 248" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
  </defs>
  <path transform="translate(-289 -320)" d="M623,565.5H291.5v-243h341v231s-1,12,14,12"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Paul. That's indeed a comprehensive answer :-)